# Error:Execution failed for task ':shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-multidex

I get the following error:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:assembleDebug]
:preBuild
:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:preDebugBuild
:checkDebugManifest
:preReleaseBuild
:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex100Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42102Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareComAstuetzPagerslidingtabstrip101Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareMeDm7BarcodescannerCore15Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareMeDm7BarcodescannerZbar15Library UP-TO-DATE
:prepareDebugDependencies
:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:collectDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:compileDebugJava
:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex
:shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':shrinkDebugMultiDexComponents'.
> 2
```

The problem exists in any higher version of `gradle` than: `"com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.1"`

I'm not sure what is going on out there. Has anyone encountered a problem like this?